# Does !fork() create a process?

Tags: c, process, fork

For instance if I call

```
if (!fork())
```

does this create a new process like calling

```
if (fork())
```

or does it not?

Comment: [in both cases] The condition can only be evaluated if fork() is actually called.

Comment: How is this *not* something you could test yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same, `fork` is evaluated before check is made.

`if (!fork())` is the same as `if (fork())` for function itself but not the same for `if` statement check.

Comment: if (fork()){//father process }         else //child process

Comment: if (!fork())  {  //child process}       else //father process

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does. In order to execute

```
if (! <expression>)
```

it first has to evaluate `<expression>`, so that it can then invert the boolean value of the expression and test it with `if`. When the expression is `fork()`, it calls the `fork` function, which creates a new process, and then returns a value in both the child and parent processes.

It's essentially just short for:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (!pid)
```